# Error with waithandles

Tags: c#, autoresetevent

I have written a simple Producer-Consumer queue. It keeps throwing an error that the safe handle is disposed.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
public class ProducerConsumer:IDisposable
{
    private Queue<string> tasks = new Queue<string>();
    Thread work;
    readonly object obj=new object();
    EventWaitHandle wh = new AutoResetEvent(true);
    public ProducerConsumer()
    {
        work = new Thread(doWork);
        work.Start();
    }
    public void doWork()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            string task = null;
            wh.WaitOne();
            lock (obj){
                if (tasks.Count > 0)
                {
                    task = tasks.Dequeue();
                    if (task == null) return;
                    else
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Performing task: " + task);
                            Thread.Sleep(1000);  // simulate work...
                        }
                }
            }

        }
    }
    public void ShutDown()
    {
        tasks.Enqueue(null);
        wh.Close();
        work.Join(); 
    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
       tasks.Enqueue(null);
       wh.Close();
       work.Join(); 
    }
    public void AddTask(string str)
       {
        lock(obj){tasks.Enqueue(str);wh.Set();}
       }
}
class Program
    {
        static EventWaitHandle _waitHandle = new AutoResetEvent(false);
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ProducerConsumer prod = new ProducerConsumer();
            prod.AddTask("Started");
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) prod.AddTask(Convert.ToString(i));
            prod.AddTask("Done");
            prod.ShutDown();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

If I change the wh.WaitOne() to the else part then it starts working

```
public void doWork()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            string task = null;

            lock (obj){
                if (tasks.Count > 0)
                {
                    task = tasks.Dequeue();
                    if (task == null) return;
                    else
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Performing task: " + task);
                            Thread.Sleep(1000);  // simulate work...
                        }
                }
                else
                    wh.WaitOne();
            }

        }
    }
```

Can somebody throw a light on why this is happening?

Comment: You're calling `wh.Close` before `work.Join` in your shutdown method, so you're potentially disposing the waithandle while it's still in `WaitOne`. You're also directly calling `task.Enqueue` rather than using your `AddTask` method, so our shutdown method won't set the waithandle.

Comment: Thank you for your response. But I do not think join is the culprit here. If join/close was the culprit it would have printed some output (atleast "Started").

Comment: I added wh.close() after work.join(). The output says "Started" and waits forever. I also used AddTask instead of enqueue in the shutdown. The output is "Started" and a a wait forevere.

Comment: Figured out the problem. Before the DoWork thread is run the AddTask calls get complete and shutdown is called. So by the time waitOne is called the handle is no longer active. If I place the join before wh.close(), the wh handle is valid but waitOne keeps waiting to be signalled. I achieved the desired results by using another waithandle. AddTask will call waitOne() on this handle before adding the next task. set will be called from doWork once the task is dequeued from the queue.